# ODE Initial Value Problem Help for Particular Solution of $y^{(3)}-2y''+y'=1+xe^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me with this initial value ODE problem?

$y^{(3)}-2y''+y'=1+xe^x$

For the characteristic equation I have $y_c=C_1+C_2e^x+C_3xe^x$. The problem for me is building the particular solution.

I thought since $f(x)=1+xe^x$ then I could start by assuming $y_p$ would be in the form of $A+Bxe^x$. To avoid duplication with $y_c$, I would multiply by x, therefore having $y_p=Ax+Bx^2e^x$.

After getting the problem wrong and seeking online help, I've been shown that the initial particular equation should be $y_p=A+Bxe^x+Cx^2e^x$ then multiplying it by $x$ to get:

$y_p=Ax+Bx^2e^x+Cx^3e^x$

I can solve the rest of the problem with this help. What I'm struggling to understand is the initial particular equation. Why would someone assume it to be $y_p=A+Bxe^x+Cx^2e^x$ where the degree for the $x$ term in $f(x)$ is only the first power? Meaning, for  $f(x)$ there is no term $x^2e^x$.

Comment: try $$x+e^x\left(-1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}\right)$$

Comment: In general you can apply variation of parameters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters